# Chaining promises resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise, jquery-deferred

I keep getting undefined error in this function. It's broken down into 5 individual functions and I'm trying to have each run after the previous one is complete but using the data returned from the previous function. I could nest all the callbacks but I'd rather use promises.

```
var checkedOutReport = function () { 
    var rootSite = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;

    //Create array with each collection site
    function getAllSites (){
        var d = $q.defer();
        var allSites = [];

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
            completefunc: function (xData,Status){
                var result = $(xData.responseXML);

                result.find('Web').each(function (){
                    var self = $(this);
                    allSites.push({
                        siteTitle: self.attr('Title'),
                        siteUrl: self.attr('Url')   
                    })
                })  
            }
        })
        d.resolve(allSites)
        return d.promise;
    }
    //Get libraries for each siteUrl
    function getSiteLibraries (allSites) {
        var siteCount = allSites.length;
        var listPromise = [];

        //Go through each site and find document libraries 
        for (var i = 0; i < siteCount; i++){
            listPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListCollection",
                webURL: allSites[i].siteUrl
            })
        }

        //Promise array contains all lists for each site
        //Get libraries for each site 
        $q.all(listPromise).then(findLibraries(listPromise))
    }
    function findLibraries (promises){
        var d = $q.defer();
        var siteCount = promises.length;
        var allLibraries = [];
        //For each site, find the document libraries
        for (var i = 0; i < siteCount; i++){
            $(promises[i].responseXML).find("List[ServerTemplate='101']").each(function(){
                var self = $(this);
                allLibraries.push({
                    listName = self.attr('Title'),
                    listId = self.attr('ID'),
                    siteUrl = allSites[i].siteUrl
                })
            })
        }
        console.log(allLibraries);
        d.resolve(allLibraries);
        return d.promise;
    }

    //CAML QUERIES
    var cQueryOptions = "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' IncludeRootFolder='True' /></QueryOptions>",
        cQueryAllCheckedOutDocuments = '<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" /></IsNotNull></Where></Query>',
        cQueryModifiedBySystemAccount = '<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Editor" /><Value Type="User">system</Value></Contains></Where></Query>',
        cViewFields = "<ViewFields Properties='True' />";

    //For each library in site collection, find documents which meet criteria 
    function searchLibraries (library) {
        var libraryCount = library.length;
        var itemPromise = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < libraryCount; i++){
            itemPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                webURL: library[i].siteUrl,
                listName: library[i].listID,
                CAMLViewFields: cViewFields,
                CAMLQuery: cQueryAllCheckedOutDocuments
            })
        }

        $q.all(itemPromise).then(parseSearchResult(itemPromise))
    }
    //Clean up result
    function parseSearchResult(result){
        var d = $q.defer()
        var resultCount = result.length; 
        var returnedFiles = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++){
            $(result[i].responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function (){
                var self = $(this);

                var fileName = self.attr('ows_LinkFilename');
                var fileUrl = self.attr('ows_FileDirRef').split("#");
                var checkedTo = self.attr('ows_LinkCheckedOutTitle');
                var modified = self.attr('ows_Modified');

                returnedFiles.push({
                    fileName: fileName,
                    fileUrl: fileUrl[1],
                    checkedTo: checkedTo,
                    modified: modified
                });
            })
        }
        d.resolve(returnedFiles);
        return d.promise;
    }

    getAllSites()
        .then(
            getSiteLibraries(allSites)
            )
        .then(
            searchLibraries(allLibraries)
            );
}
```

Comment: So does `$().SPServices()` return a promise or not? `getAllSites` would have us believe that it doesn't while `getSiteLibraries` and `searchLibraries` would have us believe that it does. –

Comment: Semicolon discipline!

Comment: Yes SPServices always returns a promise but I don't use it all the time. For example, getAllSites only makes one web call so I don't really need it there. However, searchLibraries is making multiple through a for loop so I use the promise there with $q.all()

Comment: Batman, in that case `$().SPServices` seems to be a bit odd in that it both accepts a `completefunc` callback AND returns a promise. You would normally expect one or the other. Of course, these two mechanisms *may* reveal different data which would be even odder, but nobody can tell without specific knowledge of SPServices. Does the documentation provide any insight. Also, making a single call is not, in itself, a reason for not working with the returned promise.

Comment: They both return the same information, is just that if I use a completefunc callback, I can't do asynchronous calls until whatever happens in the callback is complete, this slows down the application greatly. With promises, I can make all the web calls asynchronously store the promises in an array, then work with them from there. I'm not really an expert on promises though, still trying to figure it out and likely why I'm having problems getting things working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few problems here. I will try my best to describe as many as I can find. There are likely several more...

`d.resolve(allSites)` needs to be inside the `completefunc` callback as you don't want to resolve the promise until `allSites` is populated.

`getSiteLibraries()` and `searchLibraries()` need to return their promises.

`findLibraries()` and `parseSearchResult()` don't have any async code so there's no need to return promises, just return the results.

`$q.all(listPromise).then(findLibraries(listPromise))` actually executes `findLibraries()` immediately, simply use `$q.all(listPromise).then(findLibraries)`. Same goes for `$q.all(itemPromise).then(parseSearchResult(itemPromise))`.

Same goes for...

```
getAllSites()
    .then(
        getSiteLibraries(allSites)
        )
    .then(
        searchLibraries(allLibraries)
        );
```

Change to:

```
getAllSites()
    .then(
        getSiteLibraries
        )
    .then(
        searchLibraries
        );
```

With the above changes applied...

```
var checkedOutReport = function () { 
    var rootSite = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;

    //Create array with each collection site
    function getAllSites (){
        var d = $q.defer();
        var allSites = [];

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetAllSubWebCollection",
            completefunc: function (xData,Status){
                var result = $(xData.responseXML);

                result.find('Web').each(function (){
                    var self = $(this);
                    allSites.push({
                        siteTitle: self.attr('Title'),
                        siteUrl: self.attr('Url')  
                    })
                })  
                d.resolve(allSites); // resolve only when complete
            }
        });
        return d.promise;
    }
    //Get libraries for each siteUrl
    function getSiteLibraries (allSites) {
        var siteCount = allSites.length;
        var listPromise = [];

        //Go through each site and find document libraries 
        for (var i = 0; i < siteCount; i++){
            listPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListCollection",
                webURL: allSites[i].siteUrl
            })
        }

        //Promise array contains all lists for each site
        //Get libraries for each site 
        return $q.all(listPromise).then(findLibraries); // need to return the promise
    }
    function findLibraries (promises){
        var siteCount = promises.length;
        var allLibraries = [];
        //For each site, find the document libraries
        for (var i = 0; i < siteCount; i++){
            $(promises[i].responseXML).find("List[ServerTemplate='101']").each(function(){
                var self = $(this);
                allLibraries.push({
                    listName: self.attr('Title'),
                    listId: self.attr('ID'),
                    siteUrl: allSites[i].siteUrl
                })
            })
        }
        console.log(allLibraries);
        return allLibraries; // don't need a promise here
    }

    //CAML QUERIES
    var cQueryOptions = "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' IncludeRootFolder='True' /></QueryOptions>",
        cQueryAllCheckedOutDocuments = '<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser" /></IsNotNull></Where></Query>',
        cQueryModifiedBySystemAccount = '<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Editor" /><Value Type="User">system</Value></Contains></Where></Query>',
        cViewFields = "<ViewFields Properties='True' />";

    //For each library in site collection, find documents which meet criteria 
    function searchLibraries (library) {
        var libraryCount = library.length;
        var itemPromise = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < libraryCount; i++){
            itemPromise[i] = $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                webURL: library[i].siteUrl,
                listName: library[i].listID,
                CAMLViewFields: cViewFields,
                CAMLQuery: cQueryAllCheckedOutDocuments
            })
        }

        return $q.all(itemPromise).then(parseSearchResult); // need to return promise
    }
    //Clean up result
    function parseSearchResult(result){
        var resultCount = result.length; 
        var returnedFiles = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++){
            $(result[i].responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function (){
                var self = $(this);

                var fileName = self.attr('ows_LinkFilename');
                var fileUrl = self.attr('ows_FileDirRef').split("#");
                var checkedTo = self.attr('ows_LinkCheckedOutTitle');
                var modified = self.attr('ows_Modified');

                returnedFiles.push({
                    fileName: fileName,
                    fileUrl: fileUrl[1],
                    checkedTo: checkedTo,
                    modified: modified
                });
            })
        }
        return returnedFiles; // don't need a promise here
    }

    getAllSites()
        .then(
            getSiteLibraries
            )
        .then(
            searchLibraries
            );
}
```

Comment: Take another look at that `allLibraries.push()` statement.

Comment: Please remove that ugly [deferred anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) from that code :)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks, I've gone in and corrected those.

Comment: @anthony If I do $q.all(listPromise).then(findLibraries), how do I use the result 'listPromise' in findLibraries() since that function takes an argument. I'm having a hard time figuring out how the result from previous functions is sent to the next. For example, how does the result from findLibraries() get passed to searchLibraries() ?

Comment: @Batman it's passed as an array of results as the first parameter of the function. Read the documentation.

Comment: Batman, that's the way promise methods work. The value with which a promise is resolved is automatically passed as the one and only parameter of the function specified (not called) in a chained `.then(...)` (first arg) or `.done(...)`. Errors propagate in the same way to functions specified in chained `.then(...)` (second arg) or `.fail(...)`.

Comment: Slight qualification - jQuery promises are slightly different in that they will pass through multiple parameters, so "one and only parameter" does not apply.

Comment: I'll have a look at the documentation today. This is what I'm getting when I run things though: http://i.imgur.com/PghQ7BT.png I don't think I'm using the right result, these promisese don't really contain anything in them :/

Comment: It doesn't look empty. Put a breakpoint there and see what's inside each of the `document` objects (check the `responseXML` property, in particular). It looks like SP is returning an XML document from each of the GetListCollection calls. (They're no longer promises at this point, simply an array of results returned from the promises passed to` $q.all()`) http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems

Comment: Hi anthony, I having an issue where in getSiteLibraries I am getting a promises but when I try to send the array of promises to findLibraries(promises) I get documents which don't have a responseText. I logged the results in both functions and you can see how the data isn't the same anymore: http://i.imgur.com/EIUB1mY.png

Comment: It looks like `$().SPServices()` returns a jQuery promise, which may be incompatible with `$q` promises. I have no idea if this would make a difference or not but try wrapping it in `$q.when()`... `listPromise[i] = $q.when($().SPServices({ operation: "GetListCollection", webURL: allSites[i].siteUrl }));`

Comment: Hey Anthony, I wasn't really sure how to do what you said above but I was able to get it working by making some of the variables global within that main function. That way I don't really have to worry about passing in the data to the other functions as arguments. Probably not the optimal method but seems to work. Thanks for you help.